# Pass value in Oracle 10g from form 1 to form 2 and return another values from form2 to form1 is it possible

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

Is it possible in Oracle 10 G Froms, after calling form2 from form1, form2 on exit pass values to calling form, form1 ?
If possible what is the proper way of doing that ?

Thank you.
Regards

Answer (score 1):

Proper way to do it is to use **parameters**.

Another, not that good way, is to use **global variables**.

Open Forms Online Help system and read about both of these.